# Storing CGImage in Photos app?(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cgimage, photos

lets say I have a CGImage and want to store it in the Photos app that comes standard with every iPod Touch/iPhone how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the `CGImage` to a `UIImage`:

```
UIImage *_myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

And then use the [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) function:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

to write the `UIImage` to the Photo Album.